# How to add a three.js scene, inside a <div> to place it anywhere in my website (g58)

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm learning threeJS, I think is awesome.
I would like to know how to have my scene in a < div > to place it anywhere I want in my web-site
something like this:
https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-responsive.html

I have seen the:

`container = document.getElementById("threeScene");`

or the

`<canvas id="c"></canvas>`

it works here: http://songnes.com/g/g58.html

with their example, but when I try my own scene, is not working

maybe is the "module" or something that I just don't understand yet

thank you for all your help:
you can see the full code here: http://songnes.com/g/g58.txt

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Final GUI.DAT CONTROLLER</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
  <style>

    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    canvas {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
    .inside {
      padding: 40px;
    }
    #threeScene {
  width:360px;
  height:240px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<div class="inside">
<h2>DIRECTORY</h2>
</div>

<HR>
<div class="inside">
  <button class="accordion">3D CUBE</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="centerH3">
        <h4>Lessons From 0 to 25</h4>
      </div>
      <p id = "q1" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
      This example works<br>
      click in the cube, and you will see yellow dots!</p>

      <div class="inside">
        <div id="threeScene"></div><br>
      </div>

      <h3>START HERE: LESSON 1</h3>
  </div>
</div>

  <script>
  let container, renderer, scene, camera, controls;
let raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
let mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function init() {
    container = document.getElementById("threeScene");
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.set( 60, 60, 60 );
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 ) );
    let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 2 );
    light.position.set( 300, 200, 100 );
    scene.add( light );
    scene.add( new THREE.AxesHelper( 20 ) );
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onMouseDown );
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function onWindowResize(){
    camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight );
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
  mouse.x = ( ( event.clientX - renderer.domElement.offsetLeft ) / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - ( ( event.clientY - renderer.domElement.offsetTop ) / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

  let intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
  if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    onIntersect(intersects[0].point);
  }

}

// --------------------------------------

function onIntersect(pt) {
  let sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1, 12, 8 ),
    new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} )
  );
  sphere.position.set(pt.x, pt.y, pt.z);
  scene.add(sphere);
}




init();
animate();




let cube = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxGeometry( 20, 20, 20, 1, 1, 1 ),
  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {color: 0xff0000} )
);
scene.add(cube);

    </script>


<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML/CSS/JS here in a snippet for us to look over?

Comment: Seems to be working fine to me. `.inside` is taking up the full-width, but `#threeScene` is only 360x240 and the canvas is fitting nicely inside, also at 360x240. What's the problem?

Comment: Works for me also. Pasting directly into jsfiddle it works. I added your code to the question where it seems to work ok too.

Comment: I got it to work. This code I took line by line out, until it works. The code you see, where you click and create "yellow dots" was NOT my scene! I wanted to add my own cube. I has do much trouble. Finally I got it to work: See the final example here: https://www.songnes.com/gift/page2.html. Thanks for your answers! This problem was solved!

Comment: Full working final example is here: https://www.songnes.com/gift/page2.html

Comment: I'm having the same issue. How did you solve? @VictorM.Barba